(How) was Abaye able to endanger Rav Acha?
Kiddushin 29b tells a story of Abaye hearing that Rav Acha was coming to his study hall. It happened to be that there was a 7-headed demon in the study hall who would injure those that entered so Abaye instructed everyone not to extend lodging to Rav Acha (forcing Rav Acha to lodge in the study hall). Miraculously Rav Acha was able to dispense the demon, but afterwards indicates that if a miracle hadn't happened for him, he would have been in danger.
Several questions

Why would Abaye tell his students not to invite Rav Acha, isn't he telling them to violate the mitzvah of hachnasat orchim? (and if so why did they listen?)
Why does Abaye feel he can put Rav Acha in danger and rely on a miracle (he is actually recorded as saying "maybe a miracle will happen) - I thought there is a principle of not relying on miracles
Why all the subterfuge, if Abaye believe Rav Acha will prevail, why not let him sleep in someone's home and then tell him what the problem is and invite him into the Beit Midrash during the day?


Full text of the incident from Sefaria
שְׁמַע אַבָּיֵי דְּקָא הֲוָה אָתֵי. הֲוָה הָהוּא מַזִּיק בֵּי רַבָּנַן דְּאַבָּיֵי, דְּכִי הֲווֹ עָיְילִי בִּתְרֵין אֲפִילּוּ בִּימָמָא הֲווֹ מִיתַּזְּקִי. אֲמַר לְהוּ: לָא לִיתֵּיב לֵיהּ אִינָשׁ אוּשְׁפִּיזָא, אֶפְשָׁר דְּמִתְרְחִישׁ נִיסָּא.
Abaye heard that Rav Aḥa bar Ya’akov was coming. There was a certain demon in the study hall of Abaye, which was so powerful that when two people would enter they would be harmed, even during the day. Abaye said to the people of the town: Do not give Rav Aḥa bar Ya’akov lodging [ushpiza] so that he will be forced to spend the night in the study hall. Since Rav Aḥa bar Ya’akov is a righteous man, perhaps a miracle will occur on his behalf and he will kill the demon.
עָל, בָּת בְּהָהוּא בֵּי רַבָּנַן. אִידְּמִי לֵיהּ כְּתַנִּינָא דְּשִׁבְעָה רֵישְׁווֹתֵיהּ. כֹּל כְּרִיעָה דִּכְרַע נְתַר חַד רֵישֵׁיהּ. אֲמַר לְהוּ לִמְחַר: אִי לָא אִיתְרְחִישׁ נִיסָּא סַכֵּינְתִּין.
Rav Aḥa found no place to spend the night, and he entered and spent the night in that study hall of the Sages. The demon appeared to him like a serpent with seven heads. Rav Aḥa bar Ya’akov began to pray, and with every bow that he bowed one of the demon’s heads fell off, until it eventually died. The next day Rav Aḥa said to the townspeople: If a miracle had not occurred, you would have placed me in danger.

https://www.sefaria.org/Chidushei_Agadot_on_Kiddushin.29b.1

Also https://sefaria.org/Ben_Yehoyada_on_Kiddushin.29b.2
